# This question about Paypal for contributions should be open

Tags: discussion, status-completed

[Will I be able to contribute to Ubuntu in the future through other services in addition to PayPal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198857/will-i-be-able-to-donate-ubuntu-in-the-future-not-only-through-paypal)

This has been getting asked a bunch on the internet and it's answerable, it should be open.

Answer (score 1):

Done. Thank you for catching that one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is answerable since it asks about future changes that probably aren't known. Just so you know though, you can make a credit card payment via Paypal without having an account.

Comment: But they are known by the people who are working on the feature, whom I've asked to answer the question.